# SearchManager display another icon instead of the magnifier

Tags: android

How can I change the icon on the right of the search manager?
The default icon is a `magnifier`, but I've seen an app that does display instead of an magnifier an "OK"!

For my needs, the magnifier icon is not so good.
I use the `SearchManager` to display the history of typed words.
So a better icon is OK instead of a search icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Late to the party, but I have done this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:hint="@string/search_hint"
  android:icon="@drawable/search_icon" 
  android:searchButtonText="@string/ok_string">
</searchable>
```

Using the 'searchButtonText' attribute you can replace the default icon with your own text. 
The documentation is here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/searchable-config.html

What you won't find in the documentation is that you MUST use a string defined in your string resources, as shown above.

You can NOT do like this android:searchButtonText="OK"

Comment: Searchable doesn't have an icon option http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/searchable-config.html - I don't know how you change the icon.

Comment: You're right, it is not documented, but if you create a searchable xml and in eclipse use autocomplete (ctrl+space), you will find android:icon, with the descriptive text **If provided, this icon will be shown in place of the label above the search box**. This is the case for Android 1.6, I don't know about later versions.

Comment: It does show up in eclipse, but I don't see an effect - though I'm using the SearchView as part of my layout and not in an Action Bar (Android 3.2) - I use get and set SearchableInfo, but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Although documentations said it is *deprecated* and that the default icon is used, its still worth a shot. Try to do the following.

Corresponding with what you had in your comment regarding `meta-data` and supplying your own XML resource file for searches.

**searchable.xml**

```
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:icon="@drawable/your_OK_image"
   android:label="@string/search_label"
   android:hint="@string/search_hint" >
</searchable>
```

Comment: Thanks but i dont mean the icon on the left.
I mean the icon on the button on the right.

See this picture --> http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/images/SearchableDictionary2.png

I've tried ic_search_category_default.jpg but with no success.

Comment: Try renaming the extension to `.png` I have also revised my answer to offer other alternatives, but I think that's the one we want.

Comment: .setIcon is only for the MENU of the app, but not for the search bar at the top i think.

I have no .setIcon.
To get the search bar i only call onSearchRequested(), afterwards the search bar comes up.

In the manifest i added this to my activity:
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                       android:resource="@xml/searchable"

Comment: Chris, I updated my answer with another approach, documentations for `SearchManager` give a good understanding that the `icon` attribute is **deprecated** but, we will give it a shot. Try it and let me know.

Comment: Thanks, i've tried it but with no success. No icon change.
The app i've seen it is ALARMS for Android.
This app display instead of the searching icon another icon/button!

Comment: No problem, wish we could have figured it out.